# webalizer installation

Tags: webalizer

How can I manually install webalizer ? If there is any link providing the details to deploy it to multiple domains. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

### What is Webalizer:  (for those wondering)

Webalizer is a fast, ***free*** web server log file analysis program, written in C, which produces highly detailed, easily configurable usage reports in HTML format.  It was written to solve several problems with currently available analysis packages.

### Webalizer Features:

- It is written in C to be extremely
  fast and highly portable. On a 200
  MHz Pentium machine, over 10,000
  records can be processed in one
  second, with a 40 Megabyte file
  taking roughly 15 seconds (over
  150,000 records).
- Supports standard Common log file
  Format server logs. In addition,
  several variations of the combined
  log file Format are supported,
  allowing statistics to be generated
  for referring sites and browser types
  as well. Now also has native support
  for wu-ftpd xferlog FTP and squid log
  formats as well.
- Generated reports can be configured
  from the command line, or by use of
  one or more configuration files.
  Detailed information on configuration
  options can be found in the README
  file, supplied with all
  distributions.
- Supports multiple languages.
  Currently, Catalan, Chinese
  (traditional and simplified),
  Croatian, Czech, Danish, Dutch,
  English, Estonian, Finnish, French,
  Galician, German, Greek, Hungarian,
  Icelandic, Indonesian, Italian,
  Japanese, Korean, Latvian, Malay,
  Norwegian, Polish, Portuguese
  (Portugal and Brazil), Romanian,
  Russian, Serbian, Slovak, Slovene,
  Spanish, Swedish, Turkish and
  Ukrainian are available.
- Unlimited log file sizes and partial
  logs are supported, allowing logs to
  be rotated as often as needed, and
  eliminating the need to keep huge
  monthly files on the system.
- Distributed under the GNU General
  Public License, complete source code
  is available as well as binary
  distributions for some of the more
  popular platforms

### Webalizer Installation:

There are a few ways to install Webalizer - such as apt-get, yum, and of course from source.

**installing via apt-get or yum** is as simple as just running the command

*yum -y install webalizer*  or *apt-get install webalizer -y*

**Installing through sourcecode**

1. First we need to download the webalizer sourcode first:

   wget ftp://ftp.mrunix.net/pub/webalizer/webalizer-2.23-03-src.tgz
2. Now lets uncompress it

   tar zxvf webalizer*
3. Makesure you have gcc compiler and Gd library installed, you can installed it using yum

   yum install gcc gcc-c++ gd-devel
4. Now go into the webalizer* directory , compile and install it

   cd webalizer*
    ./configure
    make
    make install

It is installed and you can checked the version now

```
webalizer --version
Webalizer V2.23-03 ********other stuff shows here*****
```

### WEBALIZER CONFIGURATION (single domain)

1. Create a central directory for the webalizer configuration files

   mkdir /etc/webalizer
2. Create two webalizer configuration files, a.example.conf from the
   sample file and put it into /etc/webalizer directory. You need to locate the webalizer.conf.sample files and copy it to /etc/webalizer directory

   cp /usr/local/etc/webalizer.conf.sample  /etc/webalizer/a.example.com.conf
3. Modify LogFile, OutputDir and HostName of the  webalizer config files. For example, fora.example.com.conf

   vi /etc/webalizer/a.example.com.conf

and changes the content

```
LogFile /var/log/httpd/access_log
into
LogFile /var/log/httpd/access_log_1  # it depend on your httpd access_log you can search it on /var/log/httpd/ directory 
OutputDir /var/www/usage/a
into
OutputDir  /home/praetorian-id.org/public_html/webalizer  # it depend on your apache virtual directory that you set on httpd.conf (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf)
HostName       localhost
into
HostName       yourhostname.org  # it depend on your web hostname
```

Note:You may want to specify other settings specific to the domain, such as HideReferrer,HideSite, etc.

4. To process all the virtual sites, run the following command:

   for i in /etc/webalizer/*.conf; do webalizer -c $i; done

Now you can see the webalizer files on your site, example :

http://domainname.org/webalizer/usage_20100811.html

How to set Webalizer on multiple virtual domain :

Tha above tutorial are to set the webalizer for singel domain, how about if  you needed to create webalizer for multiple domain ? , you need to makesure that you have create custom log on your every virtual domain setting on httpd.conf it is usually on /usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf , here is the eample :

```
<VirtualHost 34.14.212.39>
    ServerName test.com
    ServerAlias www.test.com
    DocumentRoot "/home/domains/test.com/htdocs"
    CustomLog "/home/domains/test.com/logs/access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

as you can see above, we have set the custom log on /home/domains/test.com/logs/access_log , please also make sure you have create the  /home/domains/test.com/logs directory and set  the permission was set for  domains users

-rw-r--r-- 1 domains users 677485 Dec  1 14:45 access_log
then set the log path on your webalizer conf on /etc/webalizer/

```
# vi /etc/webalizer/test.conf
```

LogFile         /home/domains/test.com/logs/access_log
then set it per virtual domain that you have :)

and last thing ,  restart the httpd , if you are using rpm

```
# service httpd restart
```

You should see the size of the access_logs on /home/domains/test.com/logs/access_log increase , if not checked the permission and webalizer config on /etc/webalizer/test.com.conf

Do not forget to add cron so the webalizer can be udpated automaticly

```
crontab -e
```

add

```
1 * * * * /root/dowebalizer >>/dev/null 2>&1
```

i will set the crontab every 1 hour to execute the shell script on /root/dowebalizer

Now create the shell script on /root/dowebalizer

```
vi /root/dowebalizer
```

enter the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;

my @files = </etc/webalizer/*.conf>;

foreach my $file (@files) {
        chomp($file);
        system("/usr/local/bin/webalizer -c $file");
}
```

hit escape and save with w!

did this help you?   if so - leave a comment, grade it - and tag it :-)

Comment: How can I install it in a windows servers?